# Jackson loses time offset from dates when deserializing to JodaTime

Tags: java, json, jackson, jodatime

I'm trying to serialize and then deserialize a Joda DateTime object using Jackson, but it doesn't deserialize the object fully. It looks like timezone information is lost.

This code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS , false);

DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
String j = mapper.writeValueAsString(dt);
DateTime dt2 = mapper.readValue(j, DateTime.class);

System.out.println("json: " + j);
System.out.println("eq? " + (dt.equals(dt2)));
System.out.println("dates:\n" + dt + "\n" + dt2);
```

outputs this:

```
json: "2013-10-18T14:10:52.458-07:00"
eq? false
dates:
2013-10-18T14:10:52.458-07:00
2013-10-18T21:10:52.458Z
```

Is this by design? Is there anything I can do here, short of writing my own serializer/deserializer?
I've seen a few questions about this on SO, but none that deal with this aspect specifically.

I'm using Joda 2.1 and Jackson 2.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. JodaTime `DateTimeSerializer` use standard toString() method. According to [JodaTime official guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) `toString()` returns - *the standard ISO8601 string for the DateTime.* Also, standard `DateTimeDeserializer` always creates UTC datetimes.

To store TimeZone you need to store it separately with same json and use `.withZone()` method after deserialization or just create serializer and deserializer.

**UPDATE**

Version 2.2.3 have a bit extended behaviour - `DateTimeDeserializer` creates DateTime with timeZone taken from `DeserializationContext`. it may be changed with `ObjectMapper.setTimeZone()`. Default is `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")`

Comment: So there's a whole separate module devoted to handling Joda objects, but it does the serialization in the most simplistic manner possible, failing to retain crucial information... 
That's a shame. Looks like I'll have to write my own deserializer.

Comment: Instead of complaining, have you actually tried to contact authors of module, offering your help? Complaining at SO is not a productive way to work with OSS projects.

Answer (score 11):

Jackson must be told to not adjust the time-zone to that of the local context by:

```
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
```

[See this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/issues/22)

Comment: And you can set the serialization with `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID, true);`

Answer (score 1):

From [the Javadoc for AbstractInstant#equals()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) which is a superclass of `DateTime`:

> Compares this object with the specified object for equality based on the millisecond instant, chronology ***and time zone***. (my emphasis)
>
> Two objects which represent the same instant in time, but are in different time zones (based on time zone id), will be considered to be different. Only two objects with the same DateTimeZone, Chronology and instant are equal.

The two dates you show designate the same instant, but since they have different timezones JodaTime says they're not "equal".  I don't see anything wrong with how Jackson is handling them.

Comment: Right, they're not equal because Jackson isn't deserializing the time zone, which I would expect it to do.